# Won't open windows media player file

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, windows-media-player

I'm trying to open a windows media file on my desktop although it doesn't seem to open anything at all, what is the issue please?

```
elif action == "Tutorial":
                os.system("C:\\Program Files (x86)\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe" "C:\\Users\Angus\Desktop\Test.mkv"
```

Answer (score 0):

there are so many things wrong here,

1. you did not provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
2. You don't show any evidence of checking that the `elif` branch ever
   executed in the first place.
3. You are missing a close `)` on `os.system(`.
4. You use `os.system` instead of something in `subprocess` so you get no error information except the return code which you do not do anything with.
5. you do not specify a command for `os.system` like `start`, just a file which is not valid in bash, just try it in a `cmd` prompt.
6. You did not escape the file path so every space makes the program treat it as a seperate argument, you need to add `''` quotes around the file name for it to be a valid single path.
7. You are clearly on windows but not making use of the [`os.startfile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.startfile) function to do exactly what you are trying to do.